# GitFlow Initialization Error On Windows with Source Tree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

When trying to initialize GitFlow with Source Tree, I am getting errors that it cannot find the "git" command. Installing GitFlow manually does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

When Installing Git for Windows, include support for the Windows Command prompt. The new MinTTY interface is not the default for Source Tree and therefore causes the initialization of GitFlow to fail in Source Tree.

If you want to initialize GitFlow, you'll need to be able to access Git from Git Bash, which is enabled if you include support for the Windows command prompt.